# CSS: div блок c background, растянутым по ширине и сжатым по высоте

Tags: css, html, background, position

Есть изображение `img = 1000x400`, которое разделено на 3 изображения `img_r = 250x400`, `img_m = 500x400`, `img_r = 250x400`

Нужно так создать задать css свойства для `div = 600x50`, чтобы выполнялись следующие условия:

- `img_m, img_l, img_r` - это изображения для bakcground элемента div
- `img_m` сжимается до 50px по высоте и растягивается до `600px` по ширине
- `img_l и img_r` сжимаются одинаково по высоте и ширине, по высоте до
  `50px (как и img_m)`, по ширине на `250 * 50 / 400`
- `img_m` используется в `div`
- `img_l` используется в `div:before`
- `img_r` используется в `div:after`

В основном я застопорился с `img_m` - как одновременно его и вытянуть по одной оси и сжать по другой, а `img_l`, `img_r` просто сжать пропорционально и все завязано исключительно на высоте блока `div`

Comment: а можно код который есть уже? background-size: 600px 50px;

Comment: Можно воспользоваться background-size:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде как получилось

```
.xbutton {
    position:                   relative;

    display:                    inline-block;

    width:                      300px;
    height:                     75px;

    margin:                     10px;

    background-image:           url('../images/img_m.png');
    background-size:            100% 75px;  
}

.xbutton:before,
.xbutton:after {
    content:                    '';

    display:                    block;

    position:                   absolute;
    top:                        0px;

    width:                      calc(320px * 75 / 475);
    height:                     75px;

    background-size:            cover;  
}

.xbutton:before {
    left:                       calc(-320px * 75 / 475);

    background-image:           url('../images/img_l.png');
}

.xbutton:after {
    right:                      calc(-320px * 75 / 475);

    background-image:           url('../images/img_r.png');
}
```

немного смущает, что пришлось вводить формулы, основанные на знании исходных размеров:

```
calc(-320px * 75 / 475);
```

если бы и от этого как-то избавиться...